# Cloning content to a slider

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working on a responsive design, and would like some of my content in a slider when it's below a certain size. However, I would like to avoid rendering the data twice, so the idea is to clone the content and append it to the slider on `(document).ready()`, then initialise it. That way, I can show my content in the normal fashion in landscape mode, and in a slider in portrait mode (thus saving space).

```
var w = $(window).width();

if (w < 769) {

   $("#container").children(".content").each(function () {
      $(this).clone().appendTo("#slider ul").wrap("li");
   });

  initialiseSlider(); // Nothing special about this          
}
```

The content is cloned to the slider container, but for some reason, it doesn't "slide". I'm thinking it may be because the slider is initialised before it has any content, because if I hardcode it, it works fine. Does that make sense? Any ideas on how I should fix this?

Comment: You mean if you hardcode the cloned content it works great? And you're sure the 'hardcoded' content is exactly the same as the cloned content?

Comment: Yes. If I manually copy the content to the slider, it works as intended. If I clone it on `ready()` as in my function above, it doesn't work — even though the content is cloned to the correct location.

Comment: Like you said, the slider is initialised _before_ it has content in it...what happens if you _only_ initialise it after everything's been cloned? I know in some cases, like jQuery's `.dialog()`, once it's created that's it...if you want to change things, you need to utilise its option modifiers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So actually, it might have been a whole different problem, possibly related to me having two of the same slider on the page.

```
var w = $(window).width();

   if (w < 769) {

      $('#programmeList').children('article').each(function () {
         var data = $(this).clone().html();
         $('#slider ul').append('<li>' + data + '</li>')
      });
      initialiseSlider();

   }
```

Why they interfered, I don't know, as they had unique IDs and wasn't rendered at the same time anyway, but using `append()` instead of `appendTo()` helped.